# Login failed for user token-identified principal when connecting via sql_driver_manager.getConnection

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-sql-database, adal, azure-service-principal

I am trying to connect to Azure SQL using Service Principle to create views, but it says
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user  ClientConnectionId: XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX

However, with the same SPN I was able to connect and create tables, read tables.

```
import adal

resource_app_id_url = "https://database.windows.net/"
service_principal_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "XX", key = "XXX")
service_principal_secret = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "XX", key = "spn-XXXX")
tenant_id = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "XX", key = "xxId")
authority = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenant_id
azure_sql_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxxxx.windows.net"
database_name = "testDatabase"
encrypt = "true"
host_name_in_certificate = "*.database.windows.net"

context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority)
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource_app_id_url, service_principal_id, service_principal_secret)
access_token = token["accessToken"]
```

using above code I am able to create and read tables. There is a requirement to create views so I am using sql_driver_manager to connect to Azure SQL

```
properties = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.util.Properties()
properties.setProperty("accessToken", access_token)


sql_driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
sql_con = sql_driver_manager.getConnection(azure_sql_url, properties)

query = """
create or alter view test_view as select * from dbo.test_table

"""
stmt = sql_con.createStatement()
stmt.executeUpdate(query)
stmt.close()
```

this is resulting in an error:

> *Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> z:java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection. :
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: **Login failed for user token-identified principal**. ClientConnectionId:*

If I try the same with username and password instead of token, it works but I just need to use spn token for authenticating.

**Working code:**

```
sql_driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
sql_con = sql_driver_manager.getConnection(azure_sql_url, username, password)

query = """
create or alter view test_view as select * from dbo.test_table

"""
stmt = sql_con.createStatement()
stmt.executeUpdate(query)
stmt.close()
```

What is that I am missing, can someone help me understand the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Did you follow the directions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#connect-using-access-token?  You can also pass the client secret to the driver and let it generate the access token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#connect-using-activedirectoryserviceprincipal-authentication-mode

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Indeed we followed those directions. I have understood the issue, the azure_sql_url should have databaseName. This is the reason for the error. However thanks for letting me know that we can also pass the client secret to the driver. It will really help.

Answer (score -1):

You can not use that method since it was built to execute an update statement and return indexes.

See documentation.  Use the prepare() and execute() methods.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/mt-mt/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/executeupdate-method-java-lang-string?view=azuresqldb-current

```
#
#  5 - Upsert from stage to active table.
#      Grab driver manager conn, exec sp
#

driver_manager = spark._sc._gateway.jvm.java.sql.DriverManager
connection = driver_manager.getConnection(url, user_name, password)
connection.prepareCall("exec [stage].[UpsertFactInternetSales]").execute()
connection.close()
```

This is sample code from an article I wrote.  It calls a stored procedure to execute an UPSERT.  However, any DML or DDL will work as long as it does not return a result set.

Comment: There is no issue with the prepared statement. The SQL connection itself is not established when I pass properties to getConnection. The exact same code works file when I pass username and password. I have edited and added working code.

Comment: You can do what ever you want.  However, preparing a T-SQL statement and executing code is what you are doing.  You are not really executing an update.  So why use that method?  My solution is cleaner.  You should really take a look at SQL Trace or Extended Events.  You we see the prepare statement at work.  Also, I did the same action in less code!